# Where does CircleCI-2.0 store the ssh private keys?

Tags: circleci-2.0

**Aim**

To deploy docker container using ansible using CircleCI-2.0.

**Method**

A private key has been created and added using the CircleCI-2.0 UI.

*.circle/config.yml*

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: ubuntu:xenial
    working_directory: ~/project
```

**Results**

Running ansible results in:

```
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added
Permission denied (publickey,password)
```

**Discussion**

The assumption was made that the keys would have been stored in ~/.ssh, but this seems to be empty.

> Is your target host accepting this key (when tried manually)?

Yes. Log in using `ssh root@host -i key` succeeds.

> Are you using the same user in the container?

Yes. The `root` user is used both manually as from the CircleCI-2.0.

**Conclusion**

In summary, the question is where does CircleCI-2.0 store the private keys that have been submitted using the UI? The `~/.ssh` directory is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still don't get how your `config.yml` could launch ansible without a step part. Here is my findings, but I'm unsure it is what you're after, but that was too long for a comment.

According to the [documentation here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/project-walkthrough/#deploy-through-circleci) you have to add a `add_ssh_keys` with the fingerprint of your key as seen in the UI.

```
- add_ssh_keys:
    fingerprints:
      - "48:a0:87:54:ca:75:32:12:c6:9e:a2:77:a4:7a:08:a4"
```